# Changing a formwindows backcolor from a panel

Tags: windows, winforms, settings

I have a panel that is docked to the right side of a windows form. I set a color with a setting on the panel but I want to then update the main form (not the panel) backcolor to the new setting.  But when I use me.backcolor = setting it changes the panels backcolor.

This is also with VB.net windows forms with Visual Studios 2008

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the parent's `BackColor` using:

```
me.Parent.Backcolor = color;
```